# How to present several UIViewControllers at once making visible only the last one?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, segue

**This is what I need to do:**

Suppose I am at view "A", I want to show view "C" but "C" must be presented from "B".

That is A->B->C (no problem here)

> What's the issue?

I don't want `UIVIewController` B to be visible at any time in this sequence.

Comment: Present C using an animation, then pop it back off and push both B and C *without* an animation.

Answer (score 1):

My last guess would be to hide B with transparency, using some property like `view.layer.opacity` (not tested), then present C from B, and finally reset the property in the completion block.

---

Update:

Sounds like you want to use

`func setViewControllers(_ viewControllers: [AnyObject]!, animated animated: Bool)`

[Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/setViewControllers:animated:):

> Use this method to update or replace the current view controller stack without pushing or popping each controller explicitly. In addition, this method lets you update the set of controllers without animating the changes, which might be appropriate at launch time when you want to return the navigation controller to a previous state.

I guess it would look something like this:

```
self.setViewControllers( [self, B, C] , animated: true)
```

---

Have you tried:

```
self.presentViewController(B, animated: false, completion: nil)
B.presentViewController(C, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

or alternatively:

```
self.presentViewController(B, animated: false) { () -> Void in
    B.presentViewController(C, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried this, but I wan't it to be animated, a cross dissolve to be exacts.. between A and C. Also, sometimes It let me see B view for a moment

Comment: I'm not using an UINavigationController on my app, so I have no access into this method. Any way to achieve this manually?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. But I have been able to present view controllers from an invisible view controller in one of my projects...

Answer (score 1):

`self.view.hidden` ? Eg In "B":

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if someFlag == true {
        self.view.hidden = true
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a no go, it generates a blink due to the view being hidden makes it ti be a black screen