# iOS dismiss a view controller and present another one without show the base view controller

Tags: ios

I have 3 view controllers, vc1, vc2, vc3.

vc1 presents vc2 and vc3.

In vc1 I have the delegate method to dismiss vc2 and in the completion block present vc3.

It works fine. But in between the switch of views, vc1 will show. so vc2 dismiss, vc1 show, vc3 show up.

Is there any way not to show vc1 in the process? I tried to dismiss animation in both dismiss and present.

Thanks!

Comment: Show some effort by including a minimal but complete and verifiable code.

Comment: here some people tried to help me with a similar issue, no luck though, maybe you can use the insights there http://stackoverflow.com/q/31058371/2683201

Answer (score 1):

One idea might be to just present vc3 on top of vc2. Once you're ready to go back to vc1, just call `[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` and you'll pop both vc2 and vc3 without seeing vc2.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this method, but it still shows vc2 for a second when dismissing vc3

Comment: @JennyCurran Ahh, it sure does. Maybe your circumstance calls for a push and pop implementation. Then you pop back to a certain vc.

Answer (score 0):

One technique is to use UINavigationController's `setViewControllers:animated` method. Grab the `viewControllers` array from the nav controller, remove the last item (VC2), append VC3, then pass the array in to `setViewControllers`. This is essentially a pop-then-push, and it should animate the way you want.